# Mozilla FireFox extention how to write data to a file

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla

I'm pretty new to writing a ff extentions and i have this problem where i have to write to a file. I found this example but does't work for me and there are no errors so basically i have no idea why

```
                    // write to the file
                    var data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
                    var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).get("ProfD",  Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
                    file.append("test.xml");
                    var fs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);
                    fs.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20, 0664, 0); // write, create, truncate
                    fs.write(data, data.length);
                    fs.close();
```

I think that the problem is this line 
                    fs.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20, 0664, 0); // write, create, truncate have you ever encountered such problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to node's doc, the first argument of fs.write() must be the file to write to, and the second one the data, it seems not to be the case here ?

Comment: the problem for me starts here fs.init, after this line nothings is executing

Comment: where is this method from?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O#Writing_a_File